# pip with venv shows many modules installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-venv

I built Python 3.3.0 from source on my Ubuntu 13.10 laptop.

When using the `/usr/bin/virtualenv -p /python3.3.0/bin/python3 foo_virt` command to create a virtual environemnt, I see no modules installed when running `pip freeze`, which is the behavior I expect.

When using `/python3.3.0/bin/python3 -m venv foo_virt`, I see tons of modules installed:

```
(foo_virt) user@laptop:/foo_virt$ /usr/bin/pip freeze --local
Jinja2==2.7
Mako==0.8.1
MarkupSafe==0.15
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.0.0
Pygments==1.6
SecretStorage==1.0.0
... (total of 75 modules listed)
```

I tried then to install pip for that specific version of Python, by running, as per the module's documentation: `python3 get-pip.py`. But I still see all these modules:

```
(foo_virt) user@laptop:/foo_virt$ which pip
/foo_virt/bin/pip
(foo_virt) user@laptop:/foo_virt$ pip freeze --local
Jinja2==2.7
Mako==0.8.1
MarkupSafe==0.15
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.0.0
Pygments==1.6
SecretStorage==1.0.0
... (still 75 modules)
```

How do I use `venv` so no modules are installed in the virtual environment? I didn't find any option in the documentation to help me. Also, this issue is not happening on Windows 7. Thanks!

Comment: @eryksun It worked... thanks! Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash caches commands found by searching the `PATH`. You can see the current cache by entering `hash`. Adding `-r` resets the cache. `-d` will delete an individual name. Sourcing the activate script should reset the cache:

```
# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
    hash -r
fi
```

Maybe you ran the system pip before get-pip.py. In that case `hash -d pip` solves the problem.